# How can I improve the quality of my plots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I save my plots with `plt.savefig()` in PNG format the figures generated are very bad resolution. I've tried to save in PDF format and define a high number of dpi, but when I use images in that format in LaTeX, my file becomes very heavy and the PDF generated takes to much time to render.

How can I generate images with better quality and do not make my pdf generated by LaTeX so dificult to render?

[image: Example plot]:

Comment: what did to try setting the dpi to? try 300.

Comment: I've tried. But it made me to have my a file (generated by latex) very heavy to render

Comment: I can't quite tell what kind of plot this is... can you post code to reproduce it? Are those ellipses being rendered as lines or as a raster?

Comment: png with high dpi (200-300) is your best bet if vector graphics (svg/pdf) are too slow to render. there's no other solution than high resolution raster graphics.

Comment: Dpi doesn’t affect PDF output u less you rasterize the artists.  Use higher dpi in the png and latex should have no difficulty with the file size